# Should SPA use Ajax or socket.io?

Tags: node.js, single-page-application

Browsing GitHub repositories, I regularly see SPA implementations that use Ajax but not socket.io. It surprises me as I guess socket.io implementation should be faster (so you don't have to open connection every time you change the route) and therefore provide better user experience. Or do I miss something? Does Ajax-based SPA has any advantages?

Answer (score 4):

This decision solely depends on your requirements, there is no *should*. It is not even an "either .. or" decision, in some cases it could be a good idea to use an hybrid-approach.

> Does Ajax-based SPA has any advantages?

Some thoughts:

- Reusability: as you may know, socket.io is not just a wrapper around WebSockets. In fact, it uses a custom protocol that is not compatible with other WebSocket implementations - your (web-)clients must support socket.io. When using Ajax on the other hand, you could create a reusable REST-interface that is consumend by different types of applications at the same time, e.g. by your SPA and additionally by a native mobile app.
- Complexity on both client- and server side: most Javascript-frameworks used for building SPAs provide an excellent out-of-the-box support for Ajax-related communication, and Ajax calls are just plain old HTTP requests that are understood by every web server out there.
- Performance: as you pointed out, there is no need for socket.io for establishing a new connection on each request. But the thing is, this is also not necessarily the case when using HTTP. Modern browsers make use of a (more or less) smart connection management which might use the same connection for subsequent requests if the idle time between requests is not too long. If you have many concurrent users, this could be more resource-saving than using socket.io, which keeps connections open for a long period of time, even if there is no traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the absolutely correct answer @alapeno posted, there isn't a "best practice" here. It's a matter of what your use case is.

Using *Websockets* (of which socket.io is just an implementation, and IMHO there are better ones) allows you to have two-way communication between client and server, where the server can initiate the communication as long as the socket is up.

On the other hand, Ajax requires that the client initiate the communication each time.

There are advantages and disadvantages to both.

**Websockets**

*Some advantages*

- Low overhead for sending and receiving data
- Can replace "traditional Ajax" using a message format like `SwaggerSockets`
- Server can push events to the client

*Some disadvantages*

- Inefficient use of memory on the server. If you have a large number of socket connections, the amount of RAM your server process uses will increase rapidly. Some Websocket libraries are worse than others at memory management. (i.e. you'll need more servers / resources)
- There's no "standardized" way of documenting formats for sending and receiving data. You'll need to be explicit about how to invoke function on the server via an established socket, or explore using something like SwaggerSockets.
- If 3rd parties need to use your API, Websockets is probably a particularly poor choice for data exchange, given that most apps can easily invoke a REST API, but fewer are set up well to use a socket-based approach.

**Ajax**

*Some advantages*

- Lower memory requirements on the server. Since connections aren't "eternally" persistent and are designed for pull rather than push, you can probably handle a lot more clients than when using Websockets.
- Standardized documentation formats. Use Swagger, Slate, etc to create nice, readable documentation for your API, which is useful for your future self as well as any potential 3rd parties.
- Ajax is usually well understood by most web developers.
- Less overall complexity

*Some disadvantages*
 - More overhead. For every request, you'll have various headers, TCP overhead, etc, though this isn't really a huge issue. As @alapeno said, modern browsers are very smart when it comes to connection management.
 - No push notifications. If you want to know if something happened on the server, you'll have to ask. (Server-sent events are still in their infancy in terms of browser support, though that will eventually be a decent option for push.)

I'm sure there are more points that can be added to each category, but those are many of the things I think through when choosing.

A great example of varying use cases is Stripe vs. Slack.

**Stripe** has a really nice REST API, because they're aimed squarely at transactional operations. They don't make use of Websockets externally, because it just doesn't make sense for their model.

On the other hand, **Slack** is all about real-time communication. They use Websockets extensively for sending and receiving messages because it's imperative that users receive the data as soon as it's sent. Of course, Slack has a REST API too, so there's obviously room for using both within a single service where it makes sense.